# how can I assign a static ip to docker, and use it with docker-compose

Tags: docker, bridge

I installed docker in a machine running Windows Server 2012, its ip is
192.168.0.70 mask 255.255.255.0, there is no DHCP in the subnet 192.168.0.x; I set bridge connection, but the dhcp present gives 192.168.200.43.
I'd like a static ip (192.168.0.199) for the docker container (it will be xibo).
And how I will use the static ip with docker-compose?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I never tried this on Windows.

Here's a trimmed-down example of a `docker-compose.yml` I used:

```
version: '2'

services:
  halfgaarservice:
    image: someimage
    hostname: halfgaarservice
    networks:
      halfgaarnetwork:
        ipv4_address: 10.199.1.1

networks:
  halfgaarnetwork:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: "halfgaarbridge"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.199.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.199.0.1
```

When you assign static IPs, you need to define your own network, as the example shows.

When the network configuration is critical, I prefer to do all the routing myself, so I set `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    "iptables": false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

I don't know how this is configured on Windows, though.

The reason I do this, is because I have my own iptables management, and this doesn't play well with dockerd adjusting iptables at run-time.